# how to display name of user who added the text from another collection user object id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

I want to display the username who adds the text as shown in image below.i have two collections at my MongoDB cluster i.e users and posts.

[image]

Comment: can you send your `post` collection schema ?

Comment: Store userId as ObjdctID type instead of Array of object IDs. Then use lookup provided by mongo or populate method by Mongoose to get the name of the user based on the ID provided.